# Joomla show only Contact Form

Tags: joomla, joomla-component, joomla2.5

I have created a contact form for my `Joomla` site. There are two items in that contact page as `Contact` (my contact details are listed here) and `Contact Form`. I don't need that `Contact` item to display. i need to show only `Contact Form`. How could i remove `Contact` item and display only `Contact Form` ? ( I'm using Joomla 2.5 )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't edit `components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default.php` the whole point of template overrides is not to touch core files. Instead, make a copy of

`components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default.php`

and put it in

`templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/com_contact/contact/default.php`

Now you can make all the changes you want to that file without having to worry about an update overwriting your edits and if you mess up the file all you have to do is make a new copy and start over.

As for the changes you want, all of the various contact details are display between line 19-65. There is a `<p></p>` at the end of the contact info display. You can simply remove any or all of that code as needed.

Answer (score 8):

Short cut:

Go to Components -> Contacts -> Options -> Contact -> Display format: Plain